# Angularjs: Cannot get ng-enter to work

Tags: angularjs, animation, css-animations

I'm having difficulties with ng-enter and leave. The animation works if I have a css class my-animation on the ng-view div declared as .my-animation{...} in my css file. However, when I rename it to .my-animation.ng-enter{...} it stops working. Any idea of what might be wrong? I've been copy-pasting working css classes from tutorials/examples as well without any luck.

```
<div ng-view ng-cloak class=" animated slideInLeftCustom"></div>
```

works:

```
.slideInLeftCustom {
    -webkit-animation-name: slideInLeft;
    -moz-animation-name: slideInLeft;
    -o-animation-name: slideInLeft;
    animation-name: slideInLeft;
}
```

doesn't work:

```
.slideInLeftCustom.ng-enter {
    -webkit-animation-name: slideInLeft;
    -moz-animation-name: slideInLeft;
    -o-animation-name: slideInLeft;
    animation-name: slideInLeft;
}
```

I'm using AngularJS v1.2.0, latest stable download as of now.

Cheers

I updated to v 1.2.1 for animate, route and angular and it seems to be working now.

Comment: It works, it stop working: what does it mean? The animation? The css selector? Be more precise and show some code.

Comment: Hey, I thought it was well enough explained. I updated it now. Cheers

Comment: what version of Angularjs are you using?

Comment: I'm using AngularJS v1.2.0, latest stable download as of now.

Comment: Are you using the new animation system introduced with angularjs 1.1.5? Can you setup a plunker to show your configuration and problem?

Comment: I'm following http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html

I'm using v1.2 both angular and animate. I will check if I have updated ng-route. Maybe that's the thing

Example from my angular-animate file.
.reveal-animation.ng-enter {
 *

Answer (score 0):

I updated to v 1.2.1 for animate, route and angular and it seems to be working now.

I got the files from here: http://code.angularjs.org/